# Hide my div on hover but show another - HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three paragraphs

When I hover over the one that's showing already, I want to show the second paragraph below it and also replace the first paragraph by the third one?

With my css, because when I hover over the first paragraph it shows it and the second paragraph, when I try to also say 'block' the first paragraph and show the third, the UI goes crazy because its simultaneously trying to block and show, what can I do?

```css
.nodeParagraph {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 10000000;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 265px;
}

.nodeParagraph:hover+.nodeParagraph1 {
  display: block;
}

.nodeParagraph1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 10000000;
  left: 47.5px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 265px;
  display: none;
}

.nodeParagraph2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 10000000;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 265px;
}

.nodeParagraph:hover {
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: normal;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<p class="nodeParagraph"> I am the greatest in the worl... </p>
<p class="nodeParagraph1"> world </p>
<p class="nodeParagraph2"> I am the greatest in the </p>
```

Expected result:

```
I am the greatest in the 
world
```

Comment: you tagged Javascript because you are looking for an answer with JS?

Comment: I removed it :) I wasn't sure if JavaScript would be involved if I'm honest.

Comment: Ok, with JS I think it is easier, but it's up to you :)

Comment: I'm not going to shy away from any solution! Please if there is a javascript solution, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I'm using Angular by the way if that affects anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this snippet, it might help you.

```css
.nodeParagraph {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 10000000;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 265px;
}

.nodeParagraph:hover + .nodeParagraph1 {
  display: block;
}

.nodeParagraph1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 10000000;
  left: 47.5px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 265px;
  display: none;
}

.nodeParagraph2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 10000000;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 265px;
}
.nodeParagraph .show-on-hover{
  display: none;
}
.nodeParagraph:hover .hide-on-hover{
  display: none;
}

.nodeParagraph:hover .show-on-hover{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="nodeParagraph"> 
  <span class="hide-on-hover">I am the greatest in the worl...</span>
  <span class="show-on-hover">I am the greatest in the</span>
</p>
  <p class="nodeParagraph1"> world </p>
```

Comment: Simple and functional. I like.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use ellipsis then you wouldn't have to mess around with js and your html would be more semantically correct (without the need to repeat text)

```css
.paragraph {
  width:175px;  /* for demo purposes */
  
  white-space:nowrap;  /* need these three to make paragraph have ellipsis */
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

.paragraph:hover {
  white-space:normal;  /* change back to a normal p*/
}
```

```html
<p class="paragraph">I am the greatest in the world</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited: in case you want a javascript solution.

Well. First I would position your first and third paragraph one above the other and use a bit of `jquery` to replace your hover `css` properties.

your second paragraph position needed a bit of repositioning after using `position:absolute`on the other 2

I used `pointer-events:none;` on the third one as it's above the first

The basic script just shows the second paragraph on hover and I also add class `color` to first paragraph becouse one text over other will make a kind of bold effect

```js
$(".nodeParagraph").hover(function(){
    $(".nodeParagraph1").toggle();
    $(".nodeParagraph2").toggle();
    $(".nodeParagraph").toggleClass("color"); 
});
```

```css
  .nodeParagraph {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 265px;
  position:absolute;
}

.nodeParagraph1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 47.5px;
  top: 40px;
  width: 265px;
  display: block;
  display:none;
}

.nodeParagraph2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.03px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  position:absolute;
  font-weight: 300;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  width: 265px;
  pointer-events:none;
  display:none;
  
}
.color {color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="nodeParagraph"> I am the greatest in the worl... </p>
  <p class="nodeParagraph1"> world </p>
  <p class="nodeParagraph2"> I am the greatest in the </p>
```